# how to use dict in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, collections, tensor, defaultdict

I have a simple python program like

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import math

x = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "d"]
y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
z = defaultdict(float)
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[x[i]] += y[i]

result = [math.log(z[c]+1) for c in z]
```

I want to rewrite the code to tensorflow, but have no idea how to do it. Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this in tensorflow 1.8

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(["a", "b", "a", "c", "d"])
y = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

u, segment_ids, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(x)
t = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(y, segment_ids, tf.shape(u)[0])
r = tf.log(t + 1)

s = tf.Session()
print(s.run(u))
print(s.run(t))
print(s.run(r))
```

outputs

```
[b'a' b'b' b'c' b'd']
[0.4 0.2 0.4 0.5]
[0.3364722 0.1823216 0.3364722 0.4054651]
```